# How do I move content from one business unit to another within the same org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, migration

We have 3 business units in Marketing Cloud and all of our content resides in the Parent BU. I need a way to transfer all of the content.  I know I can share from one to the next but there are over 1500 items. It has been suggested that I could use AMPScript to achieve this, I have found some functions that allude to this possibility and I have the handbook however I don't know where to begin or if its even possible. Any help / insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AMPScript won't help you in this situation.  You can either:

1. Utilize Shared folders -- if they're enabled in your account
2. Build a utility with the SFMC API to move the objects.  Some assets you cannot move via API (e.g. Import Definitions, Data Extracts, etc).
3. Move the assets manually.